# Generating samples for $p(\theta_{i}|\pmb{x})$ if samples from $p(\phi|\pmb{x})$ are known

Tags: distributions, gibbs, metropolis-hastings

Suppose $X_{i}|\theta_{i} \sim D_{1}(\theta_{i})$ and $\theta_{i}|\phi \sim D_{2}(\phi)$. Moreover $\phi \sim D_{3}(c)$ where c is known. How would I generate samples for $p(\theta_{i}|\pmb{x})$ if I know samples from $p(\phi|\pmb{x})$?

Comment: That "$/$"  may be ambiguous. Could you define what you intend by $\theta_i/\pmb{x}$?

Comment: Sorry that should have been a conditional sign. Changed it.

Comment: I took the liberty of making the same change in the title

Comment: @Xi'an All $D_{1}, D_{2}, D_{3}$ are known . But except for $D_{3}$ you see everyone else's parameter is not fixed but follows a probability distribution. We know $p(\phi|\pmb{x}) \propto f(\phi, \pmb{x})$, where $f$ is some function of known $\pmb{x}$ and random variable $\phi$. So I plan on using Metropolis Hastings to pick $p(\phi|\pmb{x})$. Once I pick up $\phi$'s , I see you can sample $\theta|x_{i}, \phi$ because you can get a distribution for  $\theta_{i}|x_{i}, \phi$ . But I don't understand why would the simulation automatically marginalize to $\theta_{i}|x_{i}$?

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks a lot for your prompt response. But I still don't completely see how first generating from $p(\phi|x)$ and then from $p(\theta_{i}| x_{i}, \phi)$ is equivalent to generating from the marginal posterior of $\theta_{i}$'s (the integral). Can you please dumb it down for me and provide it as an answer instead of a comment so I can upvote and accept it ?

Comment: @Xi'an Okay I can see how first generating from $p(\phi|\pmb{x})$ and then from $p(\theta_{i}|x_{i}, \phi)$ is equivalent to $p(\phi|\pmb{x})\times p(\theta_{i}|x_{i}, \phi)$. But I dont understand why it would be equal to the integral over $\phi)$

Comment: This is the definition of marginals:$$P(\theta_i\in A)=P(\theta_i\in A, \theta_{-i}\in\Omega)$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If one considers a hierarchical model like
\begin{align*}
\phi &\sim p_3(\phi)\\
\theta_i\mid\phi &\sim p_2(\theta_i|\phi)\qquad i=1,\ldots,I\\
x_i|\theta_i,\phi &\sim p_1(x_i|\theta_i)\qquad i=1,\ldots,I
\end{align*}
the joint distribution of the parameters $(\phi,\vartheta)$ is
$$p_3(\phi)\prod_{i=1}^Ip_2(\theta_i|\phi)p_1(x_i|\theta_i)$$up to a constant. Generating realisations from that joint distribution, one produces vectors $(\phi_t,\vartheta_t)$ such that components are marginally distributed from the marginals$$\theta_i|\mathbf{x} \sim \int p_3(\phi)\prod_{i=1}^Ip_2(\theta_i|\phi)p_1(x_i|\theta_i)\text{d}\phi\text{d}\vartheta_{-i}$$Hence, when samples of $\phi$'s from the marginal $p(\phi|\mathbf{x})$ are available, completing the samples into samples of $(\phi,\vartheta)$'s can be done by simulating the $\vartheta$'s from the conditional $p(\vartheta|\mathbf{x},\phi)$.

Comment: Shouldn't the curly theta just be equal to theta, $\vartheta=\theta$ ?

Comment: This is a choice of notation to write $\vartheta=(\theta_1,\ldots,\theta_I)$.